# System of differential equations on a directed graph

Tags: differential-equations, graphs-and-networks

I want to use Mathematica to model blood flow through a capillary network. The approach we are using is going to be to create a directed graph, and have a system of differential equations at each vertex, depending on the previous vertices as inputs.

Currently, I just want to get a basic model working, where I have an input at one end of the graph, output at the other end, and at a vertex where the graph splits, half of the flow goes to the top and half to the bottom. For example, in this graph:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6}, 
           DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

I would say u[t] is the concentration (parts per million) of something in the blood at time t. Each vertex has it's own equation where

```
 u'[t] == input[t] - output[t]
```

At vertex 2, half the output goes to vertex 3, half goes to 4, etc.

I have no idea how to get started implementing this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're after.

The following is the steady state supposing null divergences except at the source:

```
g = DirectedGraph[CompleteGraph[5], "Acyclic", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
in[n_] := Tr[v[#]/VertexOutDegree[g, #]  & /@ Complement[VertexInComponent[g, n, 1], {n}]]

Solve[Join[{v[1] == 1}, Table[v[n] == in[n], {n, 2, Length@VertexList@g}]]]

(* {{v[1] -> 1, v[2] -> 1/4, v[3] -> 1/3, v[4] -> 1/2, v[5] -> 1}} *)
```